# CodeIgniter .htaccess remover index.php

Tags: codeigniter, htaccess

Começando a trabalhar com CodeIgniter e quero remover o `index.php` das URLS:

```
example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article
```

O problema é que tenho o arquivo `.htaccess` em 3 locais diferentes:

1. Esta na pasta `application`
2. Esta na pasta `sytem`
3. Esta na pasta `public_html`

Qual utilizar para remover o `index.php`, utilizando este código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve colocar fora de qualquer pasta, ou seja, na raiz do framework:

```
application/
assets/
system/
.htaccess
index.php
```

Em seguida alterar o arquivo `application/config/config.php`:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Comment: Agradecido, Amigo!

Comment: Resolveu o problema? Marque essa resposta como aceito para ajudar outros usuários. Veja como fazendo um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)! @SedineySchuster

Comment: e precisa de habilitar o mod_rewrite [link](http://gilbertoalbino.com/linux-habilitar-mod_rewrite-no-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Em alguns casos também adicione:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pasta/
```

Aconteceu comigo, passei horas para resolver.